# jQuery - Google Images functionality scroll to top of unordered list row on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to replicate google images functionality where when the user clicks on an image a div gets slid down showing the image....

What i need to figure out is how to make the browser slide down to the top of the the row of the box of the image that was clicked.

here is a link to a rough draft im working on

http://jsfiddle.net/m5sN5/2/

here is the current js as of now

```
$('li').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var active = $(this).siblings('.active');
  var posTop = ($(this).position()).top;
  if (active.length > 0) {
    var activeTop = (active.position()).top;
    if (activeTop == posTop) {
        $(this).find('.outer').finish().fadeIn('medium', function(){ 
            active.finish().toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').finish().fadeOut('medium');
        });

    } else {
        $(this).siblings('.active').finish().toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').finish().slideToggle();
        $(this).find('.outer').finish().slideToggle();
    }
} else {
    $(this).find('.outer').finish().slideToggle();
}
$(this).finish().toggleClass('active', 400);
});
$('.outer').on('click', function(e){
  return false;
});
```

so when the user clicks on a box the browser should automatically slide down to the top of the row that was clicked.

I've tried using various plugins like scrollTo but it seems to need a specific id to scroll to...this is difficult for me cause i'm using a responsive design so the top of the row might change depending on how the user resizes the browser.

any thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside your click handler:

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top},300);
```

This will run an animation, setting the scrollTop property of `body` to the top position of `this`, which should be your clicked list element.

Answer (score -1):

```
In this example I am appending the div after last element in the row.
**Here is my HTML**

<div class="container">
    <div class="box">0</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
</div>

**Here is my jQuery**

var container = $('.container');
var elements = container.children();
var oldWrapPos = 0;

$('.box').click(function(){
    container.children().removeClass('selected'); // reset selected element
    $(this).addClass('selected'); // mark new selected element
    $('.info-bg').remove(); // removing the prviously added div    
    $('.box').removeClass('edge');
    var selectedPos = $(this).index(); // get selected position
    // find wrap element:
    //var containerWidth = container.width();
    //var elementsInRow = Math.floor(containerWidth / 100 );
    var elementsInRow = 4; // use this if container's width is fixed
    var row = Math.floor(selectedPos / elementsInRow)+1;
    var wrapPos = (row * elementsInRow);

    // if selected is on last row, use as wrap the last element:
    var size = elements.length;
    if (wrapPos >= size){wrapPos = size;}
    wrapPos = wrapPos - 1;
    console.log(selectedPos);
    console.log(elementsInRow);
    var pointerPos = 40 + ((selectedPos % elementsInRow) * 110)
    console.log(selectedPos % elementsInRow);
    console.log((selectedPos % elementsInRow) * 110);
    console.log('left: '+pointerPos);
    console.log(size);
    // next line added by CrocoDillon, didn't do any cleanup of old calculations :P
    pointerPos = $(this).position().left + $(this).width() / 2 - 10;
    // end edit;
    if (wrapPos == oldWrapPos){
        $('.info-pc').css("left", pointerPos+'px');
        elements.removeClass('edge');
        $(elements[wrapPos]).addClass('edge');
        $('.info-bg').slideUp( function() { $(this).remove(); });
        $('.edge').after('<div class="info-bg"><div class="info-pc" style="left:'
                         +pointerPos+'px"></div><div class="info-cl"></div></div>');
        $('.info-bg').slideDown();
    } else {
        oldWrapPos = wrapPos;
        elements.removeClass('edge');
        $(elements[wrapPos]).addClass('edge');
        $('.info-bg').slideUp( function() { $(this).remove(); });
        $('.edge').after('<div class="info-bg"><div class="info-pc" style="left:'
                         +pointerPos+'px"></div><div class="info-cl"></div></div>');
        $('.info-bg').slideDown();
    }
});

$('html').click( function (e) { 
    if ( e.target == this )
        $('.info-bg').slideUp( function() { $(this).remove(); });
});

**Here is my CSS**

.container{
    width: 440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.info-bg{
    width: 430px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    display: none;
}

.info-cl{
    height: 100%;
}

.info-pc{
    position:absolute;
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    float: right;
    top: -10px;
}

.box{
    width:100px;
    height:170px;
    background-color: grey;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.edge{
    background-color:yellow;
}

.selected {
   background-color: red;

}
```

Here is the working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/9wftgt6j/1/